# Javascript only works when with alerts

Tags: javascript, alert

The following code loads a youtube vidéo in a player.

If I remove the two "alert", it doesn't work anymore...

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
alert('ok');
if (ytplayer) {
    alert('ok');
    loadVideo(url, start);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `alert`'s halt the thread of execution in JavaScript until you press OK, so it would point towards some asynchronous behaviour you're not handling correctly.

Comment: `alert` stops execution of JS, your code is running before the time.

Answer (score 10):

you are probably invoking the code before the page loads.  With the alert, js execution stops, allowing the page to load.  If this is correct, you need to look into the `window.onload` callback or possibly `document.ready`

```
window.onload = function(){
   // load the vid here
}
```

Comment: OK for the "execution stop". But the code I pasted is included in a function that I call after the page has loaded... And `window.onload` and `document.ready` didn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke the function after the page has been loaded completely.

```
window.onload = function() {
    loadVideo(url, start);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem with the following :

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");

if (ytplayer) {
    setTimeout( function() { loadVideo(url, start); }, 1000);
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I don't recommend setTimeout, because you are supposing your loadVideo process can be started after 1000 milliseconds in the worst case. It's bad, because you can't guarantee it will happen everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Ajax Request ?

if YES then 
put you code that didnt work at the end of

```
AjaxObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (AjaxObject.readyState == 4) {
           .
           .
           .
           .
           .

      // PUT HERE
        }
   }
```

then IF NO
put your code in function and return false or true

like this

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
alert('ok');
if (ytplayer) {
    //alert('ok');
    loadVideo(url, start);   
return true;     
}
```

hope helps