# How and where do I define JavaScript functions for a custom audio player?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to include a custom audio player in a web page following [this guide](http://alexkatz.me/posts/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/).

The HTML is

```
<audio id="music">
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<div id="audioplayer">
    <button id="pButton" class="play" onclick="play()"></button>
</div>
```

The Javascript is

```
window.onload=function() {
    var music = document.getElementById('music');
    var pButton = document.getElementById('pButton');
}

function play() {
    if (music.paused) {
        music.play();
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "pause";
        //alert("This happens");
    } else {
        music.pause();
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "play";
    }
}
```

The variables 'music' and 'pButton' are wrapped in a `window.onload` function because the DOM must be loaded for their elements to be defined (it's an error otherwise).

This code displays a "Play" button at the correct place in the page, but it does not work.  If I press the button, the page just reloads.  No music is played.  I don't understand it, but I believe it's something along this lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472961/javascript-only-works-when-with-alerts) because if I include the commented alert in the code above, the code works and the music plays as long as the alert modal is active.

In the linked question, the solution is to wrap the function `play()` in the standard `window.onload` function, too.  When I do that, however, pressing the "Play" button fails with a "ReferenceError: play is not defined" error in the console.  This, at least, makes sense: by putting `play()` in the `window.onload` function, it exists when the DOM is finished loading, but it isn't available after that for further page events.

So, to sum up,

1) The code does not work if I put `play()` outside the `window.onload` wrapper

2) The code does not work if I put `play()` inside the `window.onload` wrapper

In the standard non-quantum approximation of JavaScript, these are the only two places `play()` can be.  How do I implement a custom audio player, then?

Comment: Seems to work for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dat5rwLb/1/

Comment: Just define those variables inside your `play()` function instead of in the `onload`

Comment: Same for me, the code works perfectly as it is.

Comment: @j08691 and Run_Script Well, that's good to know, at least.  There must be something else wrong.  I get the same behavior in both Firefox and Chromium with no browser extensions.  I'll look for other errors, thanks

Comment: @charlietfl That doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

`music` and `pButton` are local to the `onload` function, so that you cannot access them outside it.

I recommend to define the `play` function inside the `onload` handler, and add it dynamically as the `onclick` handler.

You can also replace `onload` with `DOMContentLoaded`, which fires earlier, but does what it should:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var music = document.getElementById('music');
    var pButton = document.getElementById('pButton');
    pButton.addEventListener('click', function play() {
        if (music.paused) {
            music.play();
            pButton.className = "pause";
            //alert("This happens");
         } else {
             music.pause();
             pButton.className = "play";
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<audio id="music">
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<div id="audioplayer">
    <button id="pButton" class="play"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like the right idea, but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference.  I tried this idea using both a `window.onload` function and a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener exactly as shown, but the behavior is the same - nothing plays when I press the "Play" button, BUT it does if I include the alert.

Comment: @DarienMarks It plays if you include the `alert`?

Comment: Yes.  It plays as long as the alert modal is active and stops when I close the modal.  The [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472961/javascript-only-works-when-with-alerts) I referred to had a similar problem, and the answers there indicate it has something to do with asynchronization, but I can't claim to understand exactly what the issue is.